# Templating over the enum type of a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I know that enumerations can be template parameters in exactly the same way that ints can. That's nice, but I'm faced with a situation where I'd like to parametrize a template with the type of the enum itself. Take the following code:

```
class A {
  template<my_enum e>
  bool foo(int x) {
    if constexpr (e == BOO) { ... }
    if constexpr (e == YAY) { ... }
    return false;
  }
};

class B {
  template<other_enum e>
  bool foo(int x) {
    if constexpr (e == WOW) { ... }
    if constexpr (e == COOL) { ... }
    return false;
  }
};
```

I'd like to write code that's templated over both `A` and `B`, but what to do with the enums? Basically, my code would look like this (roughly):

```
template<class T, class Enum>
bool do_it(T* item, Enum e, int x) {
  item->foo<e>(x);   // This is obviously wrong.
}
```

I'm getting lost in the thicket of templating and I'm not even sure what I want is possible.

Comment: whats wrong with your `do_it` ? Looks ok

Comment: `/ This is obviously wrong.` not that obvious really

Comment: Have you tried using an `auto` template parameter, then, in the template itself, introduce `decltype` to the existing `if constexor`?

Comment: questions about non-working code should include a [mcve] and the compiler error message. It wasnt obvious, though all I had to do was to add the missing pieces and see what the compiler complains about. And frankly, thats what you could have done already.

Comment: I am afraid my last comment comes across as offensive. Not my intention. All i wanted to say is that you should not assume that things would be obvious but rather include the compiler error when the code has an error (I was able to write an answer but I had no clue what you mean until I tried ;)

Answer (score 3):

Several minor issues in your code:

- the methods are all private, you cannot call them from outside the classes
- definition of the enums is missing
- `template` keyword needed to call `foo` because its a dependant name
- `e` cannot be a function argument when you want to use it as template argument

After fixing those, the code compiles:

```
enum my_enum { BOO, YAY };
enum other_enum { WOW, COOL };

struct A {
  template<my_enum e>
  bool foo(int x) {
    if constexpr (e == BOO) {}
    if constexpr (e == YAY) { }
    return false;
  }
};

struct B {
  template<other_enum e>
  bool foo(int x) {
    if constexpr (e == WOW) {  }
    if constexpr (e == COOL) {  }
    return false;
  }
};


template<auto e, class T>
bool do_it(T* item, int x) {
  return item->template foo<e>(x); 
}

int main() {
    A a;
    do__it<BOO>(&a, 42);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7Gx6q6Gvx)